# Generate doodle report on post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

Lately I've been using doodle reporting to generate excel and pdf reports. I was doing that with a button link because the report is not dynamic.

But now I have a requirement where the parameters are dynamic, where I have a form of parameters and the users will fill these form and hit submit. The form will submit to another action and that action should generate a pdf report.

When I tried this code:

```
return new ReportResult(report, new PdfReportWriter());
```

It just generate the report in the page and I'm unable to download. Any idea how?

I've already included all the required dlls and I'm able to generate when I'm using an actionLink.

Comment: Nevermind I was able to resolve it by specifying the content type and filename: return new ReportResult(report, new ExcelReportWriter(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileName = "Report.xls" };

Comment: Add this as an answer and mark it as correct so that this question disappears from the Unanswered list :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem specify the content type and filename:

```
return new ReportResult(report, new ExcelReportWriter(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileName = "Report.xls" };
```